# How to generate a Bitcoin address in Python 3.5/6?

Tags: python, bitcoin, ecdsa

I've tried pybitcoin already, but I get a ModuleError for "services". I've tried multiple scripts from Google but they are all for Python2.

I tried to use this to get started

```
import ecdsa
return ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).to_string()
```

but it returns bytes not a string. I assume it's a version issue because it's GitHub only mentions 3.1 and 3.2.

**I want the addresses to be completely random.**

Comment: ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).to_string().hex()         (see https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/issues/56)

This may be not the answer to your question. This makes the printing looks better. I am also finding the python3 lib now. I wonder if you have some answer now?